# Given ratio, splitting input data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make Boxing module. 
I have data like these.

```
RATIO  
S:1  M:2  L:2 XL:1
```

Case 1:

```
   
color    SIZE                 
         S,    M,    L,   XL    
RED     10    20    20    8   
BLUE     5    10    10    5
WHITE   10    30    20   10
```

now if I set box qty = 30 then I expect to get

```
box_no, Color   S,   M,  L,  XL  
1       RED     5,  10, 10,  5

2       RED     5,  10, 10,  3
2       BLUE    0,   0,  0,  2     

3       BLUE    5,  10, 10,  3
3       WHITE   0,   0,  0,  2

4       WHITE   5,  10, 10,  5
5       WHITE   5,  10, 10,  5
6       WHITE   0,  10,  0,  0
```

Case 2:

```
   
color    SIZE                 
         S,    M,    L,   XL    
RED      1     2     2    2   
BLUE     1     2     2    1
WHITE    1     3     2    1
```

now if I set box qty = 30 then I expect to have everything in 1 box

```
box_no, Color   S,   M,  L,  XL  
1       RED      1     2     2    2   
1       BLUE     1     2     2    1
1       WHITE    1     3     2    1
```

how do I achieve this with php?

I am not asking whole working code. I got stuck and spent several hours w/o any progress.
Pls help me how to start or direction?

Answer (score 2):

Your ratio is currently a count. Turn it into a proper ratio.

- First sum the counts (1+2+2+1=6)
- Divide each size count  by the sum, so you get 1/6, 2/6, 2/6, 1/6.
- Then multiply those by *30 when filling the output list.
- Subtract from the availability numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't declared/initialized all the variables and didn't care with the formating but this is my idea:

```
//Sum ratios
$ratioSum = $s + $m + $l +xl;

//Count how many slots a box should have (acorrding to the smalest piece)
$boxSlotCount = $qty/$ratioSum;

//Count the size of each box bins in slots according to ratio
$binS = $s * $boxSlotCount;
$binM = $m * $boxSlotCount;
$binL = $l * $boxSlotCount;
$binXL = $xl * $boxSlotCount;

//Loop while we have items in any of the big boxes.
$i = 1;
while ($S>0 || $M>0 || $L>0 || $XL>0)
{
   echo $i;
   //If the big boxes are hold more items than a little box bin can
   //Than write the max size of a box bin
   //Otherwise write the amount of items in the big box
   echo ($S-$binS>0) ? $binS : $S;
   echo ($M-$binM>0) ? $binM : $M;
   echo ($L-$binL>0) ? $binL : $L;
   echo ($XL-$binXL>0) ? $binXL : $XL;

   //Subtract the items we put from the big boxes to the little ones
   $S -= $binS;
   $M -= $binM;
   $L -= $binL;
   $XL -= $binXL;
   $i++;
}
```